# Parse unix, UTC android

Tags: java, android, json, parsing, utc

I have JSON as in the picture below which I use in my android application. I have problems with parse of sunrise and sunset which in unix, UTC format. My question is how to **show only local hour and minute**?

[image]

Thats what I tried to sunrise but it was wrong: `sunrise.setText(json.getJSONObject("sys").getString("sunrise"));`

**Thanks for any help!**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you have a couple of issues.

The first is how to convert a Unix timestamp into a Java Date.

Like Unix timestamps, Java dates are stored internally as a long offset from a specific instant, known as the "epoch". Fortunately, they both use the same epoch. However, Unix timestamps have higher resolution.

To get a long that represents a Java date from a Unix timestamp, you need to multiply it by 1000. Then you can use the result to initialize a Java Date.
The essential thing here is to make sure that your timestamps are longs, not ints (or doubles, or any other numeric type).

So, essentially:

```
  long unixTimestamp = 1427607706;
  long javaTimestamp = unixTimestamp * 1000L;
  Date date = new Date(javaTimestamp);
```

Next, you'll need to get the numeric value from the Json, as a long, instead of a String, so use getLong instead of getString.

Finally, you'll want to format the date. Since you want just the hours and minutes, you can use:

```
String sunrise = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm").format(date);
```

and then use that value to set the value of your TextView.

Comment: Thanks you very much for you help! I have 2 questions. How to set local timezone? Show that format of time which close to users. As you know in some countries use 16:00 (24-hours format) instead of 4:00 p.m. (12-hours format). I hope you understand me. My second question is why in my case new Date is deprecated?!

Comment: Generally speaking, SimpleDateFormat will default to the user's local timezone. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateInstance(int) for the formatting that you want. For constructing the Date, use new Calendar().setTimeInMillis(long).getTime()